# How to make dynamic nested updates to a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a requirement where I've to update/merge nested child of a dict. I've tried `dict.update` but it strips the sibling (`get_users` in the the example below).

I can update a dict like `tree['endpoints']['get_tickets']['handlers']['after'] = 'new_after_handler'`, but those dict keys will be dynamic, coming from string, any idea how to achieve this?

So I basically want to get the test below passed, of course `endpoints.get_tickets.handlers` will be dynamic.

```
def test_partial_merge(self):
    source = {
        "name": "tucktock",
        "endpoints": {
            "get_tickets": {
                "path": "tickets",
                "handlers": {
                    "after": "after_handler",
                    "after_each": "after_each_handler"
                }
            },
            "get_users": {},
        },
    }
    merging = {
        "after": "new_after_handler",
    }
    expected = {
        "name": "tucktock",
        "endpoints": {
            "get_tickets": {
                "path": "tickets",
                "handlers": {
                    "after": "new_after_handler",
                    "after_each": "after_each_handler"
                }
            },
            "get_users": {},
        },
    }

    merger = Merger()
    result = merger.merge(source, merging, "endpoints.get_tickets.handlers")
    self.assertEqual(expected, result)
```

Comment: What is `Merger`?

Comment: How was it supposed to know where to find `'after'`? Are you guaranteeing that the keys are unique no matter the level they are nested too?

Comment: @Dan I'm specifying where to look for "endpoints.get_tickets.handlers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
source = {
    "name": "tucktock",
    "endpoints": {
        "get_tickets": {
            "path": "tickets",
            "handlers": {
                "after": "after_handler",
                "after_each": "after_each_handler"
            }
        },
        "get_users": {},
    },
}

merging = {
    "after": "new_after_handler",
}
expected = {
    "name": "tucktock",
    "endpoints": {
        "get_tickets": {
            "path": "tickets",
            "handlers": {
                "after": "new_after_handler",
                "after_each": "after_each_handler"
            }
        },
        "get_users": {},
    },
}


def merge(a, b, dict_path):  # modifies a in place
    for key in dict_path:
        a = a[key]
    a.update(b)


merge(source, merging, "endpoints.get_tickets.handlers".split('.'))
print(source == expected)

>>> True
```

Comment: So "modifies a in place" is the key here, I was messing up here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `Merger.merge` method you can convert the `source` to `collections.defaultdict(dict)`. Then you can iterate over the third parameter (`"endpoints.get_tickets.handlers".split('.')`) and iteratively go to the level of depth you need, then update this part.

Example:

```
def merge(source, merging, path):
    result = defaultdict(dict)
    result.update(source)
    current_part = result
    for key in path.split('.'):
        current_level = current_level[key]
    current_level.update(merging)
    return result
```